# Angular error run applyBodyHighContrastModeCssClasses

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular11

everyone

has anyone get a problem when updated to angular 11 with updated @angular/material with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_applyBodyHighContrastModeCssClasses' of undefined
at new e (main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1)
at Object.o [as factory] (main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1)
at vs.hydrate (main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1)
at vs.get (main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1)
at main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at vs._resolveInjectorDefTypes (main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1)
at new zu (main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1)
at qu.create (main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1)
at main-es2015.c8f294f80a15c1c3f55b.js:1
```

i just try to remove package-json and reinstall npm, but can't solve this error

package version:

> @angular/material, @angular/cdk: 11.2.4
>
> @angular/cli: 11.2.4

Answer (score 0):

for answers i asked in angular material github: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22250